Windows Application Verifier fails to write a stamp to log
Testing a Windows application process with AppVerifier and cannot add a stamp to its log.
I tried various cases for the command line, e.g.
appverif –stamp log –for myapp.exe –with Stamp="mystamp"

=> it just does nothing.
The 'Add Stamp' button in its GUI also does nothing.
AppVerifier version is 10.0.19041, Windows 10.
